# Problems using Spring Security with an Okta OIDC JWT

Tags: spring-security, jwt, openid-connect, okta, pkce

[PLEASE SEE UPDATE SETION BELOW FOR LATEST ITERATION]

I am trying to set up a Spring Boot REST application using Spring Security. Our front-end is authenticating our users with OIDC in Okta, and is passing the JWT in the Authorization Bearer token. Okta is using PKCE.

I am referencing the following example, and it seems to be a very simple setup:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server.html

Our Spring Boot application is only going to be a Resource Server, so I think I only need to follow the directions in sections 2.1 to 2.2.3. I have `@EnableResourceServer` in my application, and I have the following in my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource:
        jwt:
          key-set-uri: https://dcsg-hub-dev.okta.com/oauth2/v1/keysZ?client_id=???
```

When I call my app using Postman, I am getting a 401 error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid access token: eyJraWQ..."
}
```

It shows the valid token, which I can verify by calling the Okta `userinfo` endpoint. Unfortunately, it does not give me any other information.

I ended up setting breakpoints in the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` class. Stepping into the code called from this location, the error is being caused at code in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager`:

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (authentication == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid token (token not found)");
    } else {
        String token = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();
        OAuth2Authentication auth = this.tokenServices.loadAuthentication(token);
        if (auth == null) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid token: " + token);
```

Which calls the following code in the same class:

```
public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessTokenValue) throws AuthenticationException, InvalidTokenException {
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = this.tokenStore.readAccessToken(accessTokenValue);
    if (accessToken == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid access token: " + accessTokenValue);
```

It seems that the code is using the token itself as a key to retrieve the token from a hash map. As you can see above, it is using `getPrincipal()` to get the 'token'. It seems to me it thinks the token should be a user ID, which it is trying to use to find the user's token. It seems odd that it is using the token as a key to get the value, when the value is already there.

Any ideas?

<<<<<<<<<<<<<< UPDATE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

I followed the doc in this link:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.2.1.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver-jwe

My `application.yml` now looks like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://dcsg-hub-dev.okta.com
          jwk-set-uri: https://dcsg-hub-dev.okta.com/oauth2/v1/keys?client_id=
```

This is now definitely calling the JWK URI, whereas before it wasn't. However, now I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
```

I set breakpoints in that code, and for whatever reason, the `kid` that comes back in the token/JWT from Okta does not match any of the keys that are in the Okta `jwk-set-uri`.

Comment: You are correct. Although it might seem counterintuitive, it uses a String accessToken to obtain a OAuth2AccessToken (the Authentication object)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Spring Boot autoconfiguration? spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure

Comment: @EnableResourceServer is for Spring Boot 1.5.x, Spring Boot 2.1+ has it built into its http configuration. See https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/05/spring-boot-migration for more info.

Comment: I am using spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure.  
When I removed @EnableResourceServer, the invalid token error went away, but now I am just getting a plain 401. I am continuing to look into this.  
I forgot to mention above that we are using PKCE in Okta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out from Okta that this feature is not supported, you need to create your own authorization server with API Access Management.